# AngularJS - How do I split my controller?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to split my controller into two - Todos and Tags, right now I have both in one file. But I don't know how to tell angularJS. I tried to split it but then my directives in HTML were no longer valid. I mean in my HTML I have two functions from two different controllers (if I split them) and I need to call them both without making other instance of any controller. How could I do this?

I have cut some irrelevant code from this example and replaced it with dots, but I wrote comments what is there if someone found it important.

**This is my JS:**

```
var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', []);

... // here is some rest api code for Todos

todoApp.controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope, dataService) {

...

    $scope.addTodo = function () {
        var newTodo = $scope.newTodo.trim();
        if (!newTodo.length) {
            return;
        }

... // more code follows up about Todo functions

    $scope.addTag = function () {
    var newTag = $scope.newTag.trim();
    if (!newTag.length) {
        return;
    }

... // more code follows up about Tag functions
```

**and this is in my HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
...

<div class="row" id="topnav">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
            <input type="text" id="inputNewTodo" placeholder="Create new todo" ng-model="newTodo" />
        </form>
        <form ng-submit="addTag()">
            <input type="text" id="inputNewTag" placeholder="Create new tag" ng-model="newTag" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

...
</div>
```

If someone is interested you can check the live code here http://taskybird.com/

Comment: you could use `ng-controller` attribute to explicitly specify what controller for pieces of your markup

Comment: Why do you *want* to split your controllers? You should structure your reusable code in services or directives, with controllers just representing the "glue" between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a controller contains the logic dedicated to a specific view/viewmodel. If a view (or component) on your site contains these two buttons, then these functions belong to the same controller. This doesn't mean that the business logic can't be sepparated (e.g. by using services)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different controllers for different parts of your view by using `ng-controller` attribute. In case you only need to modularize your code, you can create separate modules and inject them in your main app.js file.

Eg. `var myApplication = angular.module("myApplication", ["mySharedElements"]);`
Here, `mySharedElements` is another module defined in a separate file. This approach helps to segregate different dependencies used in one controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller if you want to extend your scope or rootscope. If you don't want to extend  the scope (create child scopes); you don't need controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs follows MVC architecture as you know, Our SPA have single/multiple views and each view/feature you could have multiple controllers. Controllers is the file where we are defining the behaviour of the view objects using scope. In the each view/feature you can mention the specific  controller.